# Laravel Relationship what to use a User can speak multiple language

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am building a sign up form and on this sign up form the user to add multiple input boxes describing what languages they can speak.

I would like to be able to use Laravel relationships.

I got 3 tables
- User
- LanguageList (userid|languageid)
- Languages (definition)

I would like to confirm this is the correct relationship
A user {{one to many}} languagelist {{one to one}} language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should have post some code, anyways, if I understood you question then this is possible for a user to know multiple languages so, `User` model can have relation with many languages (language list)

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function languagelist()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('languagelist'); // user.id = languagelist.user_id
    }
}
```

In this case, default foreign key would be `user_id` and if you have different foreign key in your `languagelist` for relation between `User` and `Languagelist` then you have to pass that foreign key like

```
return $this->hasMany('languagelist', 'custom key');
```

Now, for languages listed in `languagelist` (per user) may have a `one-to-one` relation with languages stored in `languages` table and in this case you have to create a `one-to-one` relation between `languagelist` and `languages` using

```
class Languagelist extends Eloquent {
    public function language()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('language'); // default foreign key- languagelist_id
    }
}
```

You can create inverse of a relation using

```
class Language extends Eloquent {
    public function languagelist()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('languagelist');
    }
}
```

Read more on [Laravel website](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships).